# microservice architecture in node js

Tags: node.js, express, architecture, microservices

If I use different ports for different services and share the same database then can I call it microservice architecture? Like running orders services in port 8080 and running checkout service in 8081 port.

Comment: try graphql, I think it has same concept with microservices but more fun and more flexible :D
and of course, easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, it's far more complex and I suggest investing some hours in reading on internet about it from people who will be able to explain it a lot better than me, but long story short at least you should have:

- independent applications, each one with its own database. Of course each app on different ports
- you most likely want to containerize them with docker and I personally suggest orchestrating the containers with kubernetes and in this case you will need a deployment file and a clusterIP service for each application ( read more into 'pods' , 'deployments' etc on kubernetes )
- the independent services should not reach each other, in stead you use what is called `event bus`. You'll want to read more about that
- You can sync each serice's database through the event bus. You'll duplicate some data but this is an acceptable thing because storage is cheap and service independence is far more important.
- You'll need a Load Balancer to access your app eventually of course

At least this is what came in my mind in the first place. You can use it as a starting point and look into this more but as a heads up, it should not be easy. Data consistency throughout the services usually is hell.